# Why is the Shell API separate from the Windows API?

Tags: windows, api, winapi

The Windows API has functions like [CreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread), as well as shell equivalents like [SHCreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatethread) which are nearly identical in description.

Why are these APIs separate? Are they different?

Comment: @AdrianMole not really. That example is specific to the ShellExecute function, not really about the shell api as a whole. I see no reason why the shell api should have a separate function for things like creating a thread which has nothing to do with the windows shell

Comment: This is relevant only when you create shell extensions.  DLLs that are loaded into explorer.exe and add features.  Such DLLs can be very destabilizing, having explorer crash and burn gives a user a pretty bad day.  And not limited to explorer, they also get loaded into any program that uses the standard shell dialogs (OpenFileDialog, etc).  CreateThread is quite risky, SHCreateThread helps to get them right.

Comment: Different teams inside Microsoft would rather reinvent the wheel than work together?

Comment: Looking at this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/ctf) you can see that the shell API function has shell specific functionality. So yes, the functions are different.